# Black screen and distorted images on some apps after lock/hibernate

Tags: nvidia, suspend, hibernate

After closing-opening the laptop lid, some apps (e.g. Chrome, Opera, VS Code) have black screen or distorted image. Others are fine.

When I was using Windows I just close the lid when I go home and pack my things. This was never a problem.

I have this laptop ASUS ROG GL753

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. It's the same on or before installing nvidia drivers. I'm currently using the latest NVIDIA Drivers.

- kernel is 5.4.0-42-generic
- CPU: i7 7th gen
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: GTX 1050ti
- SSD: 1TB Samsung Evo

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have _exactly_ the same problem, using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Kernel 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP, nvidia-driver-440, nvidia-kernel-common-440, nvidia-utils-440. I think this happens because of a kernel upgrade or because I upgraded the nvidia driver... The problem started just a couple of weeks ago, but in the last 2 years I never had any problem with it.